# How to do backup for data in ebs snapshot?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My company has a disaster recovery requirement, this requirement considered AWS failure, such as AWS is unusable for some reason, we will need to be able to quickly restore our application in other cloud providers, like Azure.

Currently our solution is

1. taking snapshot of ec2 instance where our application is running regularly, these snapshots are the basic backup stored in AWS (invisibly on S3).
2. Take the latest snapshot at 0 am  every day, and create a EBS volume
3. Create a temporary EC2 instance
4. Attache and Mount the volume created in step 2 to the instance created in step 3.
5. Tar the files on the instance, and upload to s3 (we have some magic tools to copy files in specific bucket to Azure.).
6. Delete the volume and terminate the instance.

This solutions works, but it has some problem, is there any other better way to complete this requirement?

Comment: What are the specific problems you are having?

Comment: @NHol, the problem is that we have to create a lot of temporary ec2 instances and because the whole process takes a few hours, and this will need to run regularly, which keep adding cost, we want to save/decrease this cost for the company if there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have automated the steps (AWS CLI would suffice) then your solution is simple and effective, the only simpler thing would be to just tar the files on the source instance but that could impact whatever service it's providing.

Microsoft's solution would be to use Azure Site Recovery:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-migrate-aws-to-azure

Comment: we can tar the files on the source instances like you said, which will save some cost, but we cannot do the backup in parallel because the user(us, we're in an enterprise, have some permission constraints) can only mount one volume at one time.

Comment: What volume would you be mounting for the backup on the source? Is it to store the tar or somehow for the s3 copy?

Comment: We mount the volume created from the snapshot, then tar the content, and then copy the tar file to s3. so if we have 3 snapshots need to do the backup, we will have to mount 3 volumes unless we do it in sequence. so we have to create 3 temporary instances in this case, mount that three volume 1-1, and then to the tar and copy there. thanks. :)

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to tar on the source instance from the source ebs, rather than using an ebs snapshot. To achieve this if you have data changing on disk you could use device mapper snapshots

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/snapshot.txt

Comment: This way can be a new way for us, I will have a look and discussion with the team, see if we can make it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After had a chat with the team, we didn't go with device mapper, the reason the change is too much for us, most of the team couldn't accept it. we did some optimize, we directly create the temporary instance from the snapshot, which simplified our code base.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting an AWS outage, isn't it non effective to assume that you will be able to create another instance and restore your snapshot? I mean, if that's the case, why don't you just keep running on AWS?

I think your snapshot policy is OK to prevent EC2 failures, but not AWS. To cover the second case, backup your data to S3 and copy it periodically to Azure.

You will have extra data transfer costs (and they can get huge) but it's the safer way to ensure that you won't have to wait AWS gets back (how long could it take?) to move your data.

Comment: I think the idea is that these snapshots are being used to create temporary volumes *daily* and export the contents outside of EC2 so that they are already available in the event of an outage.  Technically, it's valid and viable but it does seem to be a case of doing things the hard way, particularly since (iirc) there has never been a concurrent catastrophic failure in two geographic regions.  It seems almost more sensible to deploy a real-time hot standby in another cloud if this is a priority failure scenario.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yeap, agree that chances are close to 0. I understood (and my answer is based on this) that he just copies data to Azure in case of failure. If I misinterpreted this point, you're completely right.